# Duplicate flagged posts - is re-use of existing answers OK?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-answers

I noticed that 95% of posts which have been auto-flagged as duplicate are re-posts of previous answers by the authors of the answers themselves. Obviously this is not plagiarism if it's the same person copying themselves.

I have been "invalid-flagging" them but I just wanted to check if this is the correct course of action here?

Comment: Obviously? http://www.ithenticate.com/plagiarism-detection-blog/bid/65061/What-Is-Self-Plagiarism-and-How-to-Avoid-It

Comment: @Eric *obviously*, it's *obvious* that the *obviousness* is mentioned in SO (CC) context, not in research context. In research self-plagiarism is dishonest, because research should differentiate between Original Research and Previous Research; on Q&A only the answer+authorship should matter, not the amount of actual research needed. Some of the (arguably) best questions on SO are awfully simple and the answers are, per se, awfully simple too... `no research` doesn't automagically mean `no usefullness to others`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends. Folks are *usually* trying to be helpful and get some points by answering questions where some new found knowledge would apply. However, these can *sometimes* be essentially the *same question, just asked differently* - at which point it's helpful if you examine them, see if perhaps some could be marked as duplicate of the best one, and answers perhaps merged.

If they're really *different* questions where the same answer applies, that's fine - just mark them as invalid. Generally, however - this auto generated flag tends to unearth a small 'strip' of questions that can probably be combined into a canonical with various stubs leading to it.

Doing the investigative work and flagging 'other' on the auto-flagged posts to inform the mods of your results is a *very* helpful thing to do, up to and including which questions should be marked as a duplicate, if you have the requisite domain knowledge to make the determination.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Lacking the domain knowledge to determine which potentially duplicate question is the "master" question - could I not just go with the highest voted one?

Comment: You can, sometimes you don't need a lot of additional insight. It's also fine if you omit that piece, a flag like "I think we've got some good duplicate / merge candidates here, but I'm not sure of the order" is also quite helpful. It lets the mods dismiss the flags that aren't actionable quickly, then go looking through the ones that need a bit of work and time.

Comment: I am curious, why are SO (and especially MSO) people so eager to mark some question as duplicate of another? What is a rationale? Is it to preserve some database space because of prohibiting new answers?

Comment: @Leos It is a lot harder for someone coming along later to find a useful answer if they have to trawl ten questions that are almost the same

Comment: I think it's worth explicitly pointing out that the duplicate answers shouldn't be deleted or downvoted if they answer the question (at least in my opinion) - answer deletion will happen anyway if the question is closed + deleted - having someone else (or no-one) get the rep in the mean time (or if that doesn't happen) just because you answered a similar question before doesn't seem fair. Especially consider the state of the close vote queue. These answerers might even have flagged the question as a duplicate already.

Comment: @HaemEternal orientation in search - this is a good point.

Comment: I completely agree with @Dukeling... personally I prefer having three good answers out there, that are the same, for each of the three questions... I agree that "in addition" it should be flagged as a duplicate question... but for the person that finds the first question without the answer how does it help for it not to be there. Bad answers will be downvoted.