# Can we auto-flag answers that are clearly copy-pasted?

Tags: feature-request, flags, duplicate-answers

I am aware the system automatically raises a flag when a user posts exact duplicates of their answers across multiple questions.

Sometimes this spammy behaviour is not *exact* duplicate though.  Near-exact duplicates could be still be detected with automated tools.  I see this sometimes with low-quality answers on old questions, which probably should have been flagged for possible spam or sock-puppeting.

- [Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25578764/674039)
- [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25578787/674039)
- [Example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25578738/674039)

Comment: I'm not sure, as I've never looked closely, but I seem to recall thinking that it doesn't require a *perfect* match. Maybe the differences I've seen in some autoflagged as dupe were due to later edits... Hmmm...

Comment: I recently flagged some answers where users posted exact duplicates of their own answers in multiple posts, but the flags got declined. So now, I think it is legitimate/acceptable for users to spam their own content.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion This might help your situation a little: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250087/2693146

Comment: I'm confused as to how 3 questions asking for the same thing can exist without any being flagged as duplicates...

Comment: Moreover the code he is proposing is not really award-winning.

Answer (score 22):

Actually, it's not a spamming, if the user posts his/her own created content, which answer the question.

However, if a single answer is answering a few questions at the same time, they are [almost] for sure duplicates, so they should be marked as duplicates.

The new user may not know about that rule, so the best way is to signal that in the comment that they should flag the question as duplicate instead of posting the same answer. Downvoting **only** because they are answering duplicate questions is, in my opinion, inappropriate.

Comment: It is still spamming, even if it's your own content.

Comment: @CodeGray "Electronic [spamming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamming) is the use of electronic messaging systems to send unsolicited bulk messages." Even if they are duplicates, they are not unsolicited.

Answer (score 13):

Duplicate answers are already automatically flagged by the system.

[Personally I think they should be blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210373/duplicate-answers-should-be-blocked-rather-than-just-flagged), but I seem to be a lone(ish) voice on this.

As a regular user, **as long as the answer is correct**, then all you can do is leave a comment for the poster telling them that they should be flagging duplicate questions rather than answering. If the answer is incorrect then obviously a down-vote is welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure if they should be blocked, since the user could persist on making trivial changes unless the system would let in. But it could be warning, that the answer is probably a duplicate, and the information why it's not welcomed.

Comment: @Donaudampfschifffreizeitfahrt - indeed, a straight block would be easily circumventable.