# User keeps posting the same answer

Tags: discussion

I was going through the review queue and noticed that one answer I saw was oddly similar to a previous one. I checked the user's page and they've answered it all three times to different questions. I gave the same comment on all about how to improve it because it's a bit short and explains nothing since it's just code.

Is this worth moderator intervention/some other action or is it best to treat them as any other poor quality answer? The questions are not duplicates, they're dealing with a similar problem but not homogenous enough that they're causing a problem.

Comment: I believe if they copy/paste the exact same answer to different questions, it automatically raises a moderator flag. I doubt it would hurt to flag with links to the other two questions and an explanation that the user is copy/pasting the same answer repeatedly, but probably not necessary due to the automatic flag.

Comment: In regards to my previous comment, [copy/paste answers do indeed raise an automatic flag.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270341/2607247)

Comment: Exact copies get autoflagged.  If each copy is a real answer to the question and is tailored to each question, then it usually isn't a bad thing. May indicate the questions are possible dupes, tho. Also, I'm assuming the user isn't spamming their stuff and the questions are on topic.

Comment: yeah that was some 1 rep user pasting a settings.xml file on multiple maven questions and it indeed did not answer any of the questions it was pasted into. I flagged it when I saw the first one and it was just a lump of xml with no explanation or anything.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson while answers that contain nothing but code aren't encouraged, I don't think we have anything in place that says they should be flagged, so be careful of that if you start seeing them rejected.

Comment: an xml file is not code and in this case it had nothing to do with questions from 4 years ago in one case. I would rather err on the side of many instead of the few in cases like this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If the answers are exact duplicates, a flag will [automatically be raised for moderator attention.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270341/2607247) For this reason, you don't really have to do much with the answers. However, do take a closer look at the questions. Verify that they truly aren't duplicates, as being able to copy and paste answers tends to imply that they are.

If their answers are *not* exact duplicates, then no flag is required. As you've already left comments to explain to the user how to improve the answers, your only other options are to downvote, or to edit to help the user out with formatting or grammar.

Answers should *never* be copied and pasted to other questions. If they are and the answers actually answer the question asked, then the questions are duplicates, the questions are just asking for tools and should be closed, or the answers are very low quality and should be edited to target the question to which they are posted. Answers should be tailored to the questions they address, no matter what.

Moderators will delete duplicated answers posted by the same user once they see the automatic flag, even if the answer has already been accepted.

Answer (score 11):

Although I am not a mod ;-), I think sometimes different questions could have the same answers. But I think, it should be examined, if the questions are really different. If not, then the questions are duplicates and they should be merged.

Comment: It should be noted that, even if the questions aren't duplicates but can have the same answer, an answer should _never_ be copied and pasted between questions. Each answer should be tailored to the question they're posted to. But you're definitely right that if they do have the same answers, you should double check and verify that they really are different questions.

Comment: @Kendra I agree in most cases, but I wouldn't close out, that significantly differing questions can have the same answer until the last byte. I don't think it happens very often, but I think it is possible. For example, if multiple problems are caused by the same rare bug in a software. Then somebody knowing this answer, can find multiple questions targeting this problem easily by running a search.

Comment: Oh, I can see it being possible that questions can share an answer and not be duplicates. The _explanation_ of the answer, however, should be targeted to the individual answers and the answer should not be just copied and pasted. If the answer and be copied and pasted, then either the questions are duplicates or the answers are incredibly poor and need more explanation. That explanation should be tailored to the separate questions, which would make the answers _not_ identical.

Comment: @Kendra I think, if I would run a query some like `SELECT COUNT(*) AS n GROUP BY content HAVING n>1` on the answers table of the SO database, the result wouldn't be empty.

Comment: @peterh that's a good question. I'm running that on Data Explorer right now, but don't expect a quick answer. This will take quite a while.

Comment: @McAdam331 The result would be highly interesting to me too :-) Please share it somehow with the community. I don't know data SE very well, but  in similar cases I would try to make a `GROUP BY MD5(content)`, maybe it would run much faster.

Comment: @peterh The results are actually quite surprising. I suspect, though, that is an answer appears more than once in the database, it's still possible one was 'deleted' from SO users to see. I would like to see if someone can explain why so many rows are returned here, or if I made a mistake in my query. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/316255/duplicate-answers

Comment: Note that those results are only for 2015. Running for all of time query timed out on me.

Comment: @McAdam331 I'd say either a bunch of them were deleted, or there's something wrong with your query. These could potentially be duplicated answers that were posted before the last sync and deleted after. Searching on the text in the one that is reported to occur six times, I only find one answer. Edit: After looking at the date of the single answer, I'm lead to believe this is the case- It was posted on the 15th, before the last sync up.

Comment: @Kendra that makes sense. I wonder, too, if edits increase the count. It's possible the edits are kept as separate 'posts' in order for us to see revision history.

Comment: @McAdam331 The six-times repeated answer suggests that a ruby gem needs attention. It's similar to the "Try rebooting your PC" answer on problems related to Windows - a standard answer that can solve many different problems.