# What should I do when one answer applies to multiple question

Tags: discussion, answers

I've recently answered the question [requireJS optional dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14164610/80779)

This question has multiple similar questions linked to it ([Requirejs ignore loading error for optional dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18990281/80779), [Null dependencies in RequireJS when ajax returns a 404](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15751642/80779)).

The answer I gave to the first question actually applies pretty directly to the other two. What should I do in this case? For some reason, simply copy-pasting the same answer with only minor modifications to make it fit question better feels wrong. But on the other hand, it is a bit silly to leave these other questions with the current less-than-satisfactory answer.

What should I do?

Comment: There are multiple examples where identical answers apply for different questions, where the question itself are not technically the same. For example, in Java, [renaming a File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/renaming-a-file-using-java) and [moving a File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645242/how-to-move-file-from-one-location-to-another-location-in-java) both use `renameTo()` even though their described behavior may be considered different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the same answer imply that the questions should be closed as duplicate? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292329/does-the-same-answer-imply-that-the-questions-should-be-closed-as-duplicate)

Answer (score 10):

If you have to copy an answer without editing it, it would be a sign the question itself is a duplicate and should therefore be flagged as a duplicate question. Otherwise, try to improve your answer to make it case-specific.

### Related

- [Duplicate flagged posts - is re-use of existing answers OK?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250087/duplicate-flagged-posts-is-re-use-of-existing-answers-ok)

Answer (score 2):

The underlying problem here is that the data structures used to represent Q&A sites are suitable for a many-to-one relationship.  One question has many answers, but each answer responds to only one question.

In real life, there are a lot of instances where the relationship is really many-to-many.  Every question has many answers, and at least in some instances, one answer responds to many questions.

What we have resorted to up to now is flagging the question as a duplicate of another question.  In many cases, this adequately covers the case at hand.  The question really is a duplicate, and flagging it as such serves both the community and the asker.

The remaining cases are where the trouble lies.  These are the cases where the questions are not duplicates, except in some very abstract sense, but an answer already posted under another question is a worthy response, word-for-word, to this question.  The community has spoken on whether cutting and pasting the answer is a service or a disservice to the community, and we have decided that it is a disservice.

The best we can come up with is flagging the question as a duplicate, and wording the alert raised with verbiage like "This question may already have an answer here".  (I forget the exact wording).  This alerts the asker to the existence of an answer elsewhere on the site, without duplicating the answer.

I note in passing that many-to-many relationships was one of the reasons why relational databases grew so rapidly in the 1980s, and displaced network databases as the centerpiece of DBMS technology.