# How can we give feedback or vote for some moderators' actions?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

I really love Stack Overflow and I already have a lot of contributions in many programming fields here, but recently I have really started hating this website because I feel like there is no democracy here. Some moderators can delete any answer and you can't reply or comment you just have to accept their decisions only because they are moderators.

For example, I believe sometimes there are two different questions that could have the same answer. Every time I answer any two questions with the same answer this moderator "Martijn Pieters" appears and deletes BOTH answers. I tried to contact him using Twitter, but he told me to use the Stack Overflow website and I can't find any way here to give my feedback about this. I really start feeling as if I am writing my answers in his own website or his Facebook wall not on a community website, so if there is no way to stop this I will NEVER give any more answers in this website.

Comment: Generally, like 99% of the time or more it's not advised to leave the same or near exact same answer to different questions. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280096/what-should-i-do-when-one-answer-applies-to-multiple-question and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250089/. You have over 3k rep so you should try to help out by closing questions that are duplicates as duplicates.

Comment: Email and off-site messaging (e.g. tweets, IMs, SMSs) about Stack Overflow is generally a bad idea.  Almost everyone is volunteering their time, and when they aren't here they probably don't have time. Any kind of ping or push risks being annoying.  Taking it to meta is a better idea.

Comment: Can you post a recent example?

Comment: These are the three answers that were removed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20512432/viewdidappear-equivalent-method-in-android/32223554#32223554 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037356/setuservisiblehint-with-fragments-for-android/32223396#32223396 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542172/horizontal-linearlayout-with-children-ordered-right-to-left/33062349#33062349 . All of them were automatically flagged by the system as being copied and pasted from other answers of yours, and Martijn acted on those flags. He provided comments on those with suggestions for how to act on them.

Comment: yes but at least the system can leave a private comments system for discussion because although i respect Martijn but he shouldn't delete both answers

Comment: @fareednamrouti yes he should delete those answers, and I had I seen the flag(s) I would have acted in exactly the same way.

Comment: It should be noted that you are not leaving good answers, either.

Comment: No democracy? Aren't the majority of mods voted in, or is that just a recent change?

Comment: They are indeed elected by the community @Trobbins. http://stackoverflow.com/election

Comment: @Trobbins Mods on beta sites are selected by SE, not voted on by the community.  Last I checked though SO was out of private beta.

Comment: thank you everyone i think  @Servy explain it enough in his answer, and sorry for this but i get mad when i felt i can't do anything

Comment: I think if the same answer works perfectly well for two questions that are *not* exactly the same... it doesn't make sense to delete either of them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a moderator takes an action that you think is inappropriate you can:

1. Flag the post, explaining what moderation action you think should be taken and why, so that the situation can be revisited by a mod again.
2. Post on the appropriate meta site explaining the situation, so that the community as a whole can discuss what happened, and what they think should happen.
3. You can click the "Contact Us" link on the bottom of the page if you feel a moderator not only took an inappropriate action in a single instance, but if there is a more significant problem with a moderator, a pattern of problematic behavior, etc.

Keep in mind that with every single one of these options you should be prepared for the fact that the mod may well have taken the appropriate action, and it may be you that doesn't properly understand the appropriate moderation action for the situation.  That doesn't mean you can't raise the issue for discussion, but be prepared for people to explain why the action taken was correct in their response to you.  It may even be best to phrase such issues as, "Why did the mod take X action?" rather than, "The mod did something wrong, go punish them."  If you are missing something, the former makes you look better, and if the mod really did make a mistake, it will become apparent to those involved if you ask the former question.

Comment: the whole point was  i didn't understand why we don't have a way to leave a discussion on the moderator actions, but this is clear enough thank you :)

Answer (score 23):

There is no way to vote for the actions of a moderator. If you really think a mod did something wrong, flag one of your answers and explain why you think so. Another moderator will review the case.

In this case though, it is pretty easy. The moderator is right. He even commented why the answer was deleted:

> Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*.

Well, did you? Did you edit your answer to tailor it to the question? If you didn't, why would you even argue? The problem is clear, a solution is given, and you don't take it. Don't complain about the moderator, review your own actions.

Comment: but if there is 2 different questions with the same answer, so they are not duplicate and there is nothing to change in the answer, what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to expand a bit on why both of your answers were deleted.

As mentioned in the comments, if you think that a single answer fits two questions, then there are two cases:

1. The questions are duplicates, because they are basically the same. In this case one of the questions should be closed as duplicate of the other one, and only the remaining open question should be answered. Deciding on which of those question should be closed might require some expertise in the topic of the questions. As a single person cannot have sufficient expertise in all potential topics, it is not (necessarily) the task of a moderator to judge, which one of those question should be closed as duplicate and which should be answered. Hence, the moderator is supposed to delete both of your answers.
2. The questions are no duplicates. In this case the questions are different enough to require a tailored answer. If you answer both questions with the same answer, then for (at least) one question your answer is assumed to not directly address that question. Again, a moderator might not be able to judge for which question your answer might be a correct fit, because the topic of the questions might not fall into the moderator's field of expertise. Therefore, the moderator is supposed to delete both of your answers in this case as well.

Based on the given arguments, it should also become clear why there is no direct way of providing feedback on the actions of moderators. It usually doesn't make sense to argue with a moderator if the discussion requires knowledge of the topic of the corresponding posts.